# Using ActiveX Control to Embed Custom Google Map into worksheet

Tags: google-maps, excel, google-maps-api-3, vba

It's very possible I'm missing a super simple step, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to get a static Google Map with an image overlay into an Excel document.

At the moment I'm using the Google GeoCoding API to pull lat & long values based on a user entered address, I then use these lat & long values to call a static Google Map centered on those values within the WebBrowser element in my excel document.

I've played around with the MapTiler software (maptiler.com) to overlay my graphic on the map, but I don't know how to get that map into Excel.

Basically, I just want my standard static Google map with a somewhat transparent image overlaid.

Comment: did you find a solution for this? Current readers may look into Office JS Content Add-Ins to achieve something similar

Answer (score 0):

Please show what you tried/researched.

I recommend you read on using the **Microsoft Web Browser ActiveX** control.
Unless you have a third party control, I think your only option is to load a HTML page with your Google Map and the overlay into the Microsoft Web Browser ActiveX control.

If you want examples see here how I embed multiple types o Google Charts into Excel: [link](http://www.analystcave.com/excel-tools/excel-google-charts/).